# Weights after a broken Collar Bone

Tags: injury, gym, weights

I broke my Collar Bone back at the beginning of April which resulted in me having an operation to repair the damage and have a metal plate put in. I was given the all clear to return to the gym yesterday and told I could do weights again as long as I didn't over do it.

Does anyone have any advise to the type of exercises I could do that will not damage my shoulder any more but will help me still build muscle again?

Comment: This is really more a question for your PT, but if you were given the all clear, then any exercise in theory should be available.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay away from isolation workouts and go to compound workouts since other bigger muscles can help out in the routines.

Types of exercises (dumbbell): Bench Press, Incline Bench Press (go light on this), Flyes

Types of exercises (cables): Seated rows, lat-pull (use wide grip so you don't use too much shoulder), Cable Cross overs, cable flyes

For Bicep/Tricep try to use cables for resistance and go slow on the reps. If you want to use dummbells go light and slow on the reps.

But, I would also stay away from barbells and go to dumbbells. It will strengthen the controlling muscles and smaller muscles that you probably haven't used in a while and that will definitely make you stronger. I injured my elbow and was out of the gym for about 10 months. And going light-med weight + 10-15 reps was really way to build the foundation again. Now I can lift heavy without my elbow hurting.